# Plotting with Numpy Arrays

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, plot

Sorry for the introductory nature of this post. I am relatively new to Python and was trying to learn to visualize data. I am currently trying to plot plot a time series of the relative frequencies of certain terms over time. An abridged version of the data I am using is listed below:

```
abridged_data = {'wandered': [[2005, 5.807135648994622e-06], [2006, 5.7273128507756315e-06], [2007, 6.7032709205293806e-06], [2008, 8.777680961941695e-06]], 'airport': [[2007, 1.0841708003745173e-05], [2008, 8.89465511574262e-06]], 'request': [[2005, 4.479519997292191e-05], [2006, 4.427159014360846e-05], [2007, 4.3048248627066294e-05], [2008, 4.081853901820637e-05]]}
```

I currently have code using the matplotlib.pyplot module that allows me access this data and to plot the frequency of one term over time, which I have pasted below.

```
x = np.array(mydata['wandered'])[:,0]
y = np.array(mydata['wandered'])[:,1]
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.show()
```

However, I haven't been able to take the data stored in the `abridged_data` dictionary and use it to plot more than one line on my graph. I was hoping someone might be able to show me the best way to access my existing dictionary to plot the data for all of the terms.

Thanks in advance for your help. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to iterate through the dictionary to retrieve all the data sets contained within. Foe example:

```
for key,value in abridged_data.items():
    x = value[:,0]
    y = value[:,1]
    plt.plot(x,y,label=key)
plt.show()
```

As pointed out in the comments, there is an ambiguity as to whether the data you are using are actually numpy arrays. If they are actually lists, then run:

```
for key,value in abridged_data.items(): 
    abridged_data[key] = np.array(value)
```

prior to using the above snippet.

Comment: this will fail: `value` is a regular python list (not `np.ndarray`)

Comment: I am assuming from the question title that they are actually numpy arrays and they have just been displayed as lists.